# eggnog doubling the ingredients, what is the new cook time?

Tags: cooking-time, beverages

**I am attempting to make homemade eggnog.** My recipe requires you to cook your mixture (which is good, as I am pregnant and can't have raw eggs but would love to taste my end result). I do however need to double all the ingredients as I am making a large quanity. **How do I determine how long to cook it on the stove top?** The original cook time is an hour. [This](http://homecooking.about.com/od/beveragerecipes/r/blbev17.htm) is my recipe if this helps anyone.

Comment: As two answers already say, your thermometer is a much more important tool here than your timer.

Answer (score 4):

The goal is not to cook the eggnog for a particular *time*, but to a particular *outcome*, in this case to hit a temperature of 160°F, which will thicken the custard (eggnog is a very thin custard).

The exact amount of time this will take depends on the size and shape of your pot, and the heat output of your element or burner, and is hard to predict.

You can use roughly double as a very rough estimate, but you will want to monitor the temperature, and remove it when it is actually done.

Answer (score 3):

It is the temperature which is critical not the time. Just heat to 160°F as in the recipe.
It will take longer to reach the required temperature

Comment: Making it in two batches may be easier.